# How to load a Dialog JQuery UI twice when this dialog load a page dynamically?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-dialog

I have this code:

```
 $(function(){

          $('#dialog').dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              closeOnEscape: false,
              modal: true,
              width: 450,
              buttons: {
                  "Enviar": function() {
                      $('#new_message').submit();
                  }
              }
          });

          $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
              $('#dialog').load('/messages/new');
              $('#dialog').dialog("open");
          });

      });
```

When I click in the in first time, the Dialog open, but, in the second time it did not open, and I know that the problem is when a use the .load method, when I comment this code, the Dialog always open when I click in the link.

How to fix it?

ps: I'm using with Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the very bizarre behaviour of jQuery dialogs, here's how I've found it's best to handle this situation:

I build my HTML like this:

```
<div id="myDialog">
</div>

... dynamically loaded HTML comes in a <div class="clearOnClose"></div> container
```

And then my javascript:

```
var myDialog = $('#myDialog');

...

if (myDialog.is('.ui-dialog-content')) {
    myDialog.dialog('open');
} else {
    myDialog.dialog({ modal: true, position: [200, 100], close: clearOnClose, etc. other options... });
}

...

// need to call on dialogs to make sure they don't interfere with each other
var clearOnClose = function (event, ui) {
    jQuery(this).find('div.clearOnClose').html('');
};
```